# Why is the same (from Android called) PHP Script only working in one folder?

Tags: php, android, xampp, directory

My Android app has a connection via PHP to a database.

It's a simple *loginScript*.

**My problem**

> I copied and pasted **EXACT** the same *loginScript* from one folder to another (in the same directory). But the called script works only in one folder.

Path to folder 1 with the *loginScript* (from android called):

```
"http://MyIpv4Adress/example/login.inc.php"
```

Path to folder 2 with the *loginScript* (from android called):

```
"http://MyIpv4Adress/myloginapp/login_register/login.php"
```

`login.inc.php` and `login.php` have different names, but **EXACT** the same content.

Calling *Path to folder 1* from android works without problems.

Calling *Path to folder 2* from android doesn't work.

I already tested some different code in *Path to folder 2*, but nothing happened.

> So my app is not possible to call *Path to folder 2* but *Path to folder 1*. **WHY?**

Both folders are in the htdocs folder of xampp.

I think it's not necessary to add the code of my *loginScript*, because *Path to folder 2* doesn't work with different scripts too.

> You can open `login.inc.php` and `login.php` with the normal browser and both works.
>
> Both scripts aren't throwing any errors. Not in PHP and not in the logcat of Android Studio.

Comment: Does the one that doesn't work from Android work correctly with a regular browser?

Comment: @Dave Yes, it does.

Comment: What happens when you try? Does it throw any errors, either to the android app or in the server error log?

Comment: @aynber No errors are thrown.

Comment: Extension `.inc.php` can be interpreted by php differently than a normal `.php` file. Try to look this way in php.ini file.